# Is this a true statement ? $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying to confirm my understanding of $A \subseteq B$ so would this be a true statement ?

$\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\})$

I am guessing it is since $\mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\}) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$

And so every element in $\{\emptyset\}$ is contained in $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)$. Would this be correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ is true for **every** set $X,$ seeing as
$$\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\mathcal P(X)\iff\emptyset\in\mathcal P(X)\iff\emptyset\subseteq X,$$
and $\emptyset\subseteq X$ is always true.

Comment: Okay got it thank you !

Answer (score 2):

$A = \{\emptyset\}$ is the set that contains the empty set.

$\mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\}) = \mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. And a set is always its own subset, so the statement (which was not about strict subsets) is true.